# Stop rails loading associated models when checkin if record is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an object called message which belongs to carrier, company, country

I allowing for a bulk insert of users via a CSV - what i want to do before is make sure every row is valid before i import it (so that i can inform the user prior to the beginning the import)

So i have created a method that loops through all new data and does Message.new(PARAMS_IN_HERE) and then call `.valid?` on it, which is fine and achieves the desired results.

However, when i look in the logs i see loads of queries like this

```
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Carrier Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" WHERE "carriers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Which is obviously quite wasteful as one its doing the same query multiple times. Is there a way to make rails cache the value/preload when it needs to look for/ or just stop it happening?

This is what my message class look like

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :carrier
  belongs_to :country

  before_validation :set_default_details, on: :create

  private

  def set_default_details
    if self.user.present?
      self.carrier_id = self.user.company.tariff.carrier_id
      self.country_id = self.user.country_id
      self.company_id = self.user.company_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Working on same CSV bulk import issue, right now. So, I’m interested in a solution to multiple query. I did validate just CSV headers and wrapped the create loop inside a transaction. If any error raises it rolls back and adds an error showing it as f.error in form. But maybe there is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation references `self.user` but that's not defined in the model snippet you posted.

If your validations refer to to association objects, like `self.company`, give those objects to the constructor: `Message.new(company: company)` rather than `Message.new(company_id: company.id)`. If necessary look up all dependent objects ahead of time - this can be done with a single query - and store id -> object mapping in a Hash.

Similarly you can have validations reference fields like `company_id` but it's probably better to use association objects everywhere.